# Real size of a bare java.lang.Object in JVM

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm

According to [Memory usage of Java objects: general guide](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml) :

### In Hotspot:

> a normal object requires 8 bytes of "housekeeping" space;
>
> arrays require 12 bytes (the same as a normal object, plus 4 bytes for the array length).

### Object size granularity

> In Hotspot, every object occupies a number of bytes that is a multiple
>   of 8. If the number of bytes required by an object for its header and
>   fields is not a multiple 8, then you round up to the next multiple of
>   8.
>
> This means, for example, that:

- a bare Object takes up 8 bytes;
- an instance of a class with a single boolean field takes up 16 bytes: 8 bytes of header, 1 byte for the boolean and 7 bytes of "padding" to make the size up to a multiple of 8;
- an instance with eight boolean fields will also take up 16 bytes:

  - 8 for the header, 8 for the booleans; since this is already a multiple of 8, no padding is needed;
- an object with a two long fields, three int fields and a boolean will take up:

  - 8 bytes for the header;
  - 16 bytes for the 2 longs (8 each);
  - 12 bytes for the 3 ints (4 each);
  - 1 byte for the boolean;
  - a further 3 bytes of padding, to round the total up from 37 to 40, a multiple of 8.

### My question:

A bare java.lang.Object has no fields. So `new Ojbect()` will take 8bytes in heap.

But when i test size of `new Object()` by using  [instrumentation agent](http://www.javamex.com/classmexer/) util.

```
System.out.println(MemoryUtil.deepMemoryUsageOf(new Object()));
```

The result is `16`, not `8`. Can anybody tell me why?

---

EDIT:

As far as i known, [the object header](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~stefank/6989984.1/raw_files/new/src/share/vm/oops/markOop.hpp)'s size is 4byte on x86.

And also **object header contains the lock info for sync**.

```
//  32 bits:
//  --------
//      hash:25 ------------>| age:4    biased_lock:1 lock:2 (normal object)
//      JavaThread*:23 epoch:2 age:4    biased_lock:1 lock:2 (biased object)
//      size:32 ------------------------------------------>| (CMS free block)
//      PromotedObject*:29 ---------->| promo_bits:3 ----->| (CMS promoted object)
```

**So an Object's Overhead is 4byte(object header) + 4byte(class pointer) = 8byte.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [interesting presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/DawidWeiss/sizeofobject-how-much-memory-objects-take-on-jvms-and-when-this-may-matter) may give you additional insights.

Basically, since memory alignment and padding are 8 bytes in a 64-bit JVM, the Object overhead is 16 bytes: each attribute (header and class reference) takes 8 bytes. See slide 38 in the presentation. Note however the overhead is reduced to 12 bytes when using JVM option `-XX:+UseCompressedOops`.

Comment: Your line is very usefull.

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted does not mention about lock_type reference. See [this](http://www.trevorpounds.com/blog/?p=351). Apart from reference to class(8 bytes), it will have reference to lock_type. Also check 'Memory Usage' section [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/).